# php JSON to JQuery

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am creating Google chart using MYSQL data through PHP. Below is the part of jQuery.

```
  $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        //dataType: 'JSON',
        url: "/php/abc.php",
        success: function (data1) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            // Add legends with data type
            data.addColumn('string', 'type');
            data.addColumn('number', 'value');
            //Parse data into Json
            var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data1);
            //var jsonData = (data1);
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                alert (jsonData[i].length);
                alert (jsonData[i].type);
                data.addRow([jsonData[i].type,  parseInt(jsonData[i].value)]);
            }
```

I am getting below output from php when i check direct php page on browser

```
 {"type":"New_Userstory","value":"10"}{"type":"Active_Userstory","value":"20"}{"type":"Resolved_Userstory","value":"30"}{"type":"Closed_Userstory","value":"40"}
```

but through json it is not showing anything, says incorrect character '{'. When i have used **header('Content-Type: application/json');** or dataType: '**JSON**', this eror is gone but result is "undefined" any other way to get this JSON ?

Comment: That's not valid JSON coming from your PHP. Show your PHP code. (Note, you can't just echo json_encode multiple times and expect it to work.)

Comment: $this->temp_sql_display = "SELECT * FROM SalesSummary";
   
   try {
    
    $result = $this->hookup->query($this->temp_sql_display);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     $this->json = json_encode($row);

     echo $this->json;
    }   
   }

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work. You need to generate an array in the loop, then after the loop json_encode the array.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the correct JSON output.

```
{"type":"New_Userstory","value":"10"}{"type":"Active_Userstory","value":"20"}{"type":"Resolved_Userstory","value":"30"}{"type":"Closed_Userstory","value":"40"}
```

The correct JSON output would be

```
[
  {
    "type": "New_Userstory",
    "value": "10"
  },
  {
    "type": "Active_Userstory",
    "value": "20"
  },
  {
    "type": "Resolved_Userstory",
    "value": "30"
  },
  {
    "type": "Closed_Userstory",
    "value": "40"
  }  
]
```

According to your PHP Code, here is what you need to change.

```
$this->temp_sql_display = "SELECT * FROM SalesSummary"; 
try { 
    $result = $this->hookup->query($this->temp_sql_display); 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    { 
        $this->json[] = $row; 
    }    
    echo json_encode($this->json); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Samay, how can i get this from MySQL data fetch. I have shared the MYSQL fetch code in above comment.

Comment: You need to create an array when running the while loop. Try doing this     $this->json[] = $row; inside the while loop and move the echo json_encode($this->join) after the while loop.

Comment: @Samay That will have the same problem. You don't want to json encode inside the loop, you want to generate the array, then json encode.  (Edit: As your latest update shows)

Comment: @SwapnilRanadive - Kindly refer the code in the answer.

Comment: @SwapnilRanadive - Welcome. Would appreciate accepting the answer if it works.